# Change color in second activity using button in main activity = crashes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, background-color

I'm new to coding and I've been working on this (seemingly simple) task for hours, have tried posts on forums but to no avail.

I have buttons on my main activity and want to change the background color of the 2nd activity (LampActivity) based on a color assignment in the button's intent.

The following code results in a crash on startup - please help! -=\

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.lightbox;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1=findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3=findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4=findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5=findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6=findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button button7=findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button button8=findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button button9=findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button button10=findViewById(R.id.button10);
        Button button11=findViewById(R.id.button11);
        ImageButton button12=findViewById(R.id.button12);


        }
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LampActivity.class);

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.button1:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yellow Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.yellow);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

**2nd Activity:**

```
package com.example.lightbox;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import android.content.Intent;

public class LampActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lamp);
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/charcoal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:text="@string/yellow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:text="@string/orange"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/pink"
        android:text="@string/pink"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:text="@string/purple"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.079" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="@string/blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/aqua"
        android:text="@string/aqua"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/lime"
        android:text="@string/lime"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="@string/green"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.107" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/sequence"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button12"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button10" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/rainbow_button"
        android:src="@drawable/rainbow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button11" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blurb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/blurb"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_lamp.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LampActivity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Logcat Report:**

2020-01-26 09:02:18.546 17378-17378/? I/xample.lightbo: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-01-26 09:02:18.580 17378-17378/? E/xample.lightbo: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-01-26 09:02:18.581 17378-17378/? W/xample.lightbo: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-01-26 09:02:18.800 17378-17411/com.example.lightbox D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2020-01-26 09:02:18.800 17378-17411/com.example.lightbox W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2020-01-26 09:02:18.794 17378-17378/com.example.lightbox W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:61): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7422 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c147,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0 app=com.example.lightbox
2020-01-26 09:02:18.817 17378-17411/com.example.lightbox D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-01-26 09:02:18.819 17378-17411/com.example.lightbox D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-01-26 09:02:18.832 17378-17411/com.example.lightbox D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-01-26 09:02:18.888 17378-17378/com.example.lightbox D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-26 09:02:18.891 17378-17378/com.example.lightbox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lightbox, PID: 17378
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lightbox/com.example.lightbox.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:145)
        at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:131)
        at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:6510)
        at com.example.lightbox.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:32)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: can you add crash to understand exact meaning and help you.

Answer (score 0):

*Step 1* `seecond_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LampActivity"
    android:id="@+id/second_layout">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Step 2*

```
package com.example.lightbox;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1=findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3=findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4=findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5=findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6=findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button button7=findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button button8=findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button button9=findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button button10=findViewById(R.id.button10);
        Button button11=findViewById(R.id.button11);
        ImageButton button12=findViewById(R.id.button12);


        }
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LampActivity.class);

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.button1:

                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                        extras.putInt("bgColor", R.colo.yellow);
                        pass.putExtras(extras);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

*Step 3* `SecondActivity.java`

```
public class LampActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConstraintLayout mRoot;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lamp);

        mRoot = findViewById(R.id.second_layout);
        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        int color = data.getIntExtra("bgColor", -1);
        mRoot.setBackgroundColor(color);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I tried this and got  some errors:

In step 2, "pass.putExtras(extras);"
"pass" is red

In step 3, "int color = data.getIntExtra("bgColor", -1);
"getIntExtra" is also red

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion didn't work, but after researching I pooled together code that did work:

**activity_main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/charcoal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:text="@string/yellow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:text="@string/orange"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/pink"
        android:text="@string/pink"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:text="@string/purple"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.079" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:text="@string/blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/aqua"
        android:text="@string/aqua"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/lime"
        android:text="@string/lime"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:text="@string/green"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.107" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/sequence"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button12"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button10" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/rainbow_button"
        android:src="@drawable/rainbow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button11" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_lamp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LampActivity"
    android:id="@+id/lampScreen">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1=findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2=findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3=findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4=findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5=findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6=findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button button7=findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button button8=findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button button9=findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button button10=findViewById(R.id.button10);
        Button button11=findViewById(R.id.button11);
        ImageButton button12=findViewById(R.id.button12);


        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        button8.setOnClickListener(this);
        button9.setOnClickListener(this);
        button10.setOnClickListener(this);
        button11.setOnClickListener(this);
        button12.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LampActivity.class);

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Yellow Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.yellow);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Orange CLicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.orange);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button3:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Red Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.red);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button4:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pink CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.pink);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button5:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Purple CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.purple);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button6:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blue Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.blue);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button7:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Aqua Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.aqua);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button8:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Lime Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.lime);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button9:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Green Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.green);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button10:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "White Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.white);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button11:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sequence Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.white);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button12:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rainbow Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent.putExtra("bgColor", R.color.white);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**LampActivity:**

```
public class LampActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lamp);
        ConstraintLayout lamp = findViewById(R.id.lampScreen);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int bgColor = bundle.getInt("bgColor", -1);
        lamp.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(bgColor));

    }
}
```